# How to implement document parenting in node/MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to implement my own acl module for node using mongodb. I know some of them already exists, but for experience purpose I want to create my own :).

We will have `roles`, and `users`. Each `role` will have some `permissions` on some `resource`. Each `role` may have a parent(s) role(s) too. This parenting part is currently blocking me.

1) How can I implement that ? I read another SO post pointing me to mongodb doc : [Embedding vs linking](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#SchemaDesign-EmbeddingandLinking), so I the best way seems to be to implement stuff with references :

```
roles collection :
[{
  _id: "my_role_1"
 },
 {
  _id: "my_role_2",
  parents: ["my_role_1"]
},
 {
  _id: "my_role_3",
  parents: ["my_role_2"]
}]
```

Is it the right way to do ? As nodejs is asynchronous, it's a nightmare to get the "parenting tree" of my_role_3 (I `mean my_role_3 -- my_role_2 -- my_role_1`) :

```
function getRoleParenting(roleName, callback) {
    this.db.collection('roles', function(err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({role: roleName}, function(err, role) {
            role.parents.forEach(function(roleParent) {
                // I know I should call the function recursively,
                // But I can't figure out how to get the full "tree"
                // at the end... In a sync way, I would use "return"...
                // How can I do here ?
                // getRoleParenting(roleParent._id);
            }
       });
    });
}
```

2) As I said, node_acl is a node module already doing that. I saw that they create one collection per role. As I may have many, many different roles, I decided to avoir this solution 'cause in mongodb docs they say performances are better when queries implies a few number of collection. Is my choice correct, avoiding this method ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/ would make this a far easier pattern to handle.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that ! I'll have a look at it !